# http post, byte size limitation on post - python

Tags: python, http, post, byte

I have been reading the contents of a file which is continuously updated. I'm Trying something like this.

```
offset = 0
now = datetime.now()  
FileName = now.date()  
logfile = open("FileName","a")  
logfile.seek(offset)  
data = logfile.read()  
try:  
    http post  
except:    
    Exceptions...
```

Now I want to read only the specific number of bytes from the file. Just because if I lose the Ethernet connection and get the connection again, it takes a long time to read the whole file. So that Can someone help me reg this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .read() with a numeric argument to read only a specific number of bytes, e.g. read(10) will read 10 bytes from the current position in the file.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: I have already tried. but I find some data loss, specifically when I use a numeric value as an offset.